# InputConnection inactive on EditText on listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have an `CustomListView`. When I click on an item, they display more information, in particular a `LinearLayout` with a number of `EditText` (depending of the item). 
When I  have one item on my list, I haven't problem (if I click on the `EditText`, the `KeyBoard` appear and I can enter the text). But when I have several item on my `list`, when I click on the `EditText`, the `KeyBoard` appear, the cursor too but it disappears just after and I have the `Error` :

> W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextBeforeCursor on inactive
>   InputConnection W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextAfterCursor on
>   inactive InputConnection

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    MyObject myObject = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.mName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.name);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        final LinearLayout layoutDataToSent= (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutDynamique);
        for(int i = 0; i < Info.getNbByteWrite(myObject); i++) {
            EditText edittext = new EditText(mContext);
            edittext.setText("0x");
            edittext.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            layoutDataToSent.addView(edittext);
        }
        ...
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    LinearLayout mLayoutWrite = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_write);
    holder.mName.setText(Info.getName(myObject.getUuid().toString()));
    if (viewSelected == position) {
        if((myObject.getProperties() & MyObject.PROPERTY_WRITE) > 0){
            mLayoutWrite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Thank you for your help

---

***Edit :***

After serveral tries, I think the problem comes from my layout.

If I set the height of my Listview to  :

- match_parent or wrap_content, I have the problem,
- fix to 950dp for example 1000dp for example, I haven't the problem to write text on edittext but I have problem to see all data (I can't scroll the listview).

This is my layout containing the listview (it's a fragment):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/my_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is list_item.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"  />
    ...
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_write"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" >
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/layoutDynamique"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>
       ...
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#aaa" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try add theese lines to your code. I should reset any Input Connection

```
...
EditText edittext = new EditText(mContext);
edittext.setText("0x");
edittext.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layoutDataToSent.addView(edittext);

//add folowing
edittext.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.restartInput(edittext);
....
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it changes nothing

Comment: try replacing my solution with ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
    .showSoftInput(edittext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);

Comment: Thank you to deal my problem but It change nothing. After serveral tries, I think the problem comes to layout (cf edit)

Answer (score 0):

Suggested the approach which works on "most" devices.

```
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

for your EditText view (after you called `editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);).'

You should probably also set:

```
 editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Also it is stated that your EditText should not be the first view to receive focus when activity starts (if it is - just requestFocus() from another view).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I add "setTextIsSelectable" , the keyboard don't appear. The two other lines (setRawInputType and requestFocus) change anything

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake, the change hasn't corrected the problem. After serveral tries, I think the problem comes to layout (cf edit)